# reactor design pattern in a single thread vs multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted, reactor

I've been reading about the reactor design pattern, specifically in the context of the Python Twisted networking framework. My simple understanding of the reactor design is that there is a single thread that will sit and wait until one or more I/O sources (or file descriptors) become available, and then it will synchronously loop through each of those sources, doing whatever callbacks specified for each of these sources. Which does mean that the program as a whole would block if any of the callbacks are themselves blocking. And regardless, once all callbacks have executed, the reactor goes back to waiting for more I/O sources to become ready.

What are the pros and cons of this, compared to asynchronously looping through each source as they appear, i.e. launching a separate thread for each source. I imagine this may be less efficient if all your callbacks are very fast, as the OS now has to deal with managing multiple threads and swapping between them. But it seems that it's now impossible to block the main program, and as an added benefit, the main reactor can keep listening for sources. In short, why does something like Twisted not do this, instead keeping to a single-threaded model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the pros and cons of this, compared to asynchronously looping through each source as they appear, i.e. launching a separate thread for each source.

What you're describing is basically what happens in a multithreaded program that uses blocking I/O APIs.  In this case, the "reactor" moves into the kernel and the "asynchronous looping" is the kernel completing some outstanding blocking operation, freeing up a user-space thread to proceed.

The cons of this approach are the greatly increased complexity with respect to thread-safety (ie, correctness) that it incurs compared to a strictly single-threaded approach.

The pros are better utilization of multiple CPUs (but running multiple single-threaded event-driven processes often offers this benefit as well) and the greater number of programmers who are familiar and comfortable (though often mistakenly so) with the multithreading approach to concurrency.

Also related, though, are the PyPy team's efforts towards providing a better abstraction over the conventional multithreading model.  PyPy's work towards Software Transactional Memory (STM) could offer a system in which work is dispatched asynchronously to multiple worker threads without violating the assumptions that are valid in a strictly single-threaded system.  If this works out, it could offer the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1):

> But it seems that it's now impossible to block the main program,

I'm not a Python guy but have done this in the context of Boost. Asio. You're correct—your callbacks need to execute quickly and return control to the main reactor. The idea is to only use asynchronous calls in your callbacks. For example, you wouldn't use an API for sending an IP datagram that blocks and returns a status code. Instead, you'd use a non-blocking API where you register success and failure callbacks. This lets the call send call return immediately. The reactor will then call the success/failure callback once the OS has dealt with the packet.